# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express startup failure, new install, Windows 8: An error occurred during encryption

Tags: sql-server-2008

New installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on Windows 8.  Using system account to run the service.  SQL Server error log contains, "An error occurred during encryption."  The solutions in the following links did NOT help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blakhani/archive/2009/11/24/sql-server-2005-express-setup-failure-with-error-an-error-occurred-during-encryption.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920114

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be best to post this question on Server Fault since it doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: This can be moved to Stackexchange. This might not be exact  fits for serverfault as it is related to SQL Server installation. Can you please add errorlog contents it would be located at Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n files. see latest file.  If you are unable to find use this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx